# equations for an open ball in a normed space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space. Show that for an open ball $B_1(0) \subseteq V$, it holds true that:

$∂B_1(0) = \{x \in V: d(x, 0) = 1\}$

where $d(x, 0) = \|x\|$. Also, figure out the elements of $\overline{B_1(0)}$.

Thanks in advance! I'm not that much into normed spaces yet and have yet trouble dealing with these constructions.

Comment: Is your metric defined as $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$? If yes, then you should be able to see it now, if not, please give the definition of the metric you use.

Comment: In the task given, it just says $d(x, 0) = \|x\|$, that's it. I assume that it's the metric naturally induced by $\|x\|$ for any $d(x, y)$, so exactly the one you said, but I posted it the way it was written.

Comment: well but this metric must be defined somewhere (in your lecture perhaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\{x_k\}$ is a sequence in $B_1(0)$ that converges to a point $x \in V$.  Then $$\|x\| \le \|x - x_k\| \le \|x_k\| < 1 + \|x - x_k\|$$ for all $k$. Take the limit as $k \to \infty$ to conclude that $\|x\| \le 1$.  Thus $$ \overline{B_1(0)} = \{x \in V : \|x\| \le 1\}.$$ Can you show that $B_1(0)$ is open? Once you have established that, use the fact that
$$ \partial A = \overline A \setminus \mathrm{int} A$$ to conclude $$\partial B_1(0) = \overline{ B_1(0)} \setminus B_1(0) = \{x \in V : \|x\| = 1\}.$$

Comment: Thanks. But could you please go into more detail on why the inequalities in the first line $\|x\| \le \|x - x_k\| \le \|x_k\| < 1 + \|x - x_k\|$ are true? Everything below that seems logical to me, but I can't quite see why this line is true.

Comment: It's just the triangle inequality: $$\|x\| = \|(x - x_k) + x_k\| \le \|x - x_k\| + \|x_k\|$$